# Nuget, Package Manager console(powershell) issue

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I am getting the following error during Package Manager Console initialisation in Visual Studio 2012. I am on windows 8. I couldn't find any information online, has anyone come across the same problem and found a solution yet, please let me know.

Thanks

```
The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: Microsoft.PowerShell.Core, C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\types.ps1xml(2977) : Error in type "System.Security.AccessControl.ObjectSecurity": Exception: The getter method should be public, non void, static, and have one parameter of type PSObject.

The term 'Get-ExecutionPolicy' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Answer (score 0):

Which edition of Visual studio is installed on the machine ?
Did you try running it as Admin ?
Also can you try enabling Net3.5 as per instructions here @ [Powershell runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588885/powershell-runtime)