# Powershell runtime

Tags: visual-studio-2010, powershell, windows-8, nuget

I'm running VS 2010 under Windows 8. After installing NuGet, and running Package manager console I get the following message:

`Error: The Package Manager Console requires PowerShell 2.0 runtime, which is not detected on this machine. Please install the PowerShell 2.0 from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929 and restart Visual Studio.`

I know that PowerShell 3.0 is installed automatically along with Windows 8. Why would this error message pop up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While the `Windows Powershell 2.0 Engine` feature is on by default in Windows 8, you need to turn on .Net 3.5 to actually use it, as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/windows-powershell/install/installing-the-windows-powershell-2.0-engine):

> On Windows 8, the Windows PowerShell 2.0 Engine feature is turned on
> by default. However, to use it, you need to turn on the option for
> Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5, which it requires.

Follow the steps in the above link to get it working.

Answer (score 2):

While PowerShell 3.0 on Windows 8 is installed by default, PowerShell 2.0 isn't. You can go into Programs and Features and select "Turn Windows Features On or Off" and from there you can select Windows PowerShell 2.0 for installation.

Comment: Check my answer. It is actually enabled.

Comment: Ah, so PowerShell is only partially installed by default.  That makes a lot of sense, eh.  ;-)