# VS2012 PowerShell errors

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, powershell

I am trying to use PowerShell in order to install some graphing packages in Visual Studio 2012 Express Edition, on Windows 7.

When I try to open the PowerShell Console, I get the following error:

> The Package Manager Console requires PowerShell 2.0 runtime, which is not detected on this machine. Please install the PowerShell 2.0 from http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929 and restart Visual Studio.

When I go to this URL, all of the information is in regards to Windows Vista and XP. I also read that the PowerShell runtime is included in the 4.5 Framework, but this could be incorrect.

Has anyone else ran into this error? Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588885/powershell-runtime)

Comment: I tried using that option, and it did not work, when I went to turn the features on or off there was no PowerShell 2.0 Node

Comment: Sounds like at some point you've installed NuGet (Package Manager Console).  Grab version 3.0 of powershell from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595 (it's part of the "Windows Management Framework).

Comment: Unfortunately when I try to use that, none of them are applicable to my computer (that's the message that I get)

Comment: Have you verified you are running the latest NuGet?  Open up VS Tools | Extensions and Updates...  Look under the Updates area to see if there is an update to NuGet.

Comment: Yup, no updates available :(, this is very confusing because on my other computer it works perfectly fine...but I need it on my work laptop

Comment: Are you running windows 7 starter edition?

Comment: I have Ultimate edition, I am very very confused